# Getting access to all variables inside a loop outside the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, variables, for-loop

so I'm trying iterate over req.files this is req.files looks like when I 
  `conosle.log(req.files)`

```html
{ logo:
   File {
     domain:
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        members: [Object] },
     path: '/var/folders/v7/qqwh5nds511b28p8r4006pq40000gn/T/upload_3e7a4c1ee6461ad12c70140857d925cc',
     name: 'logo.png',
        },
  homeSliderImage:
   File {
     domain:
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        members: [Object] },
     path: '/var/folders/v7/qqwh5nds511b28p8r4006pq40000gn/T/upload_424f4be7ef9a8cc1331da4ca126cd806',
     name: 'apple.png',
        }
}
```

here I have my loop where I'm looping through req.files and I'm getting the keys of the object(logo and homeSliderImage) after I get the keys I want to be able to get the path to each one. Which I do but I want to be able to have access to both of these paths outside this loop. if I `console.log(newPath)` outside the loop it would only log the last key.path, i want all of them.

```js
    var file = req.files

        for (var key in file) {
          if (file.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var newPath = req.files[key].path
      
          }
        }
```

Comment: Well sounds like you need an array of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a collection such as an array, this should be initialized outside of the loop, so that the value is not reset every time, such as:

```
var paths = []; // array to hold all the paths

var file = req.files    

for (var key in file) {
  if (file.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    paths.push(req.files[key].path); // add the value to the paths array
  }
}
```